# Undefined Index with PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

```
    ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
    ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: q_sold in C:\wamp\www\aaa\mup.php on line 93
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0039  144192  {main}( )   ..\mup.php:0
```

I got Undefined Index for this code:

```
<table align="center" border="2">
   <tr>
    <td align="center"> <font color="">  Quantity Sold:</td>
    <td align="center"> <font color="">  Month:</td>
   </tr>

<?php
include 'connect.php';


$bogart=mysqli_query($con," SELECT  `month`, sum(q_sold) as sold_sum
FROM  `samsung_store` group by `month` order by sold_sum desc
LIMIT 1 ") or die (mysql_error());

$count=mysqli_num_rows($bogart);

while($baragan=mysqli_fetch_array($bogart)){

if($count % 2 == 0){
$color="#EDEDED";
$count--;
}
else{
$color="white";
$count--;
}
?>

 <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
      <td> <?php echo $baragan['q_sold']?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $baragan['month'] ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>

</form>
</table>
```

I just need to remove the error. which I don't know How I tried to put "@" sign at the beginning of the: but didn't work

> $bogart=msqli_query

Sorry I'm a beginner please bare. Thanks.

Comment: `sum(q_sold) as sold_sum` means that it should be accessed as `$baragan['sold_sum']` - you are naming it differently within the query

Comment: Oh thanks. Sorry foprgot to look at that. I'm too fool. Haha sorry fot bothering you guys. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<td> <?php echo $baragan['q_sold']?></td>
```

Why do you access the index `q_sold`, when you are selecting in your query the alias named `sold_sum`?

Change it to:

```
<td> <?php echo $baragan['sold_sum']?></td>
```

---

Hint: Use `print_r($baragan);` to see what is going wrong here.

Comment: Thanks :) sorry for bothering I forgot to look at that. Too fool for that. Sorry and thank you so much.